# How to "uninstall" Strange Eons

Tags: java, software-uninstall

I installed Strange Eons and now I want to get rid of it.
The last step of the install was:

> Strange Eons includes a command to integrate with the desktop. This
>   command should work with any desktop that supports the freedesktop.org
>   standards (including Gnome and KDE). To perform this step, enter the
>   following command:
>
> ```
> java -cp strange-eons.selibrary register
> ```

How can I undo this command?

Answer (score 0):

Acting on the advice of the Strange Eons support person,
I went to {~/.local/share/applications} and deleted the
Strange Eons folders[.desktop entries]. Then I deleted the Strange Eons
files from my desktop. It seems to be gone now. :-)